# Android: Fragments, how to save state of Listview that has a custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment with a listview that has a custom adapter. The fragments are accessed via tabs.

When I click fragmentA, it will render some images and show them in a list.

When I click fragmentB, it will show something else.

When I click fragmentA again, it will **re-render** the images. How do I save it's state, to avoid the re-rendering?

**FragmentA**:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    public ImageView my_img;
    private static int hitcount = 0;
    public Bitmap mybitmap = null;
    public ProgressDialog pd;
    private View myFragmentView;
    public HashMap<Integer,String> urlList = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    public String inputUrl = "http://google.com/image.png";
    ListView listview;
    public String[] imgs = new String[20];
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenta, container, false);
        listview = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        if(hitcount < 1) {
            urlList = ((JSONActivity)getActivity()).imageList;
            for(int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++)
                imgs[i] = (String)urlList.values().toArray()[i];
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), imgs );
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        listview.setActivated(true);
        hitcount++;
        return myFragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well as a "quick&dirty" solution you could always try setting `this.setRetainInstance(true)` in the `onCreate()` of your FragmentA. But that's really rarely the best solution. It's a bit frowned upon in StackOverflow even :D I'll come back to this in the morning and give you a full answer

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I put `this.setRetainInstance(true)` in my fragments onCreate() method. When I click a different fragment and return to the original fragment, the images are re-rendered.